# Convert MS Access DataBase to mysql DataBase

Tags: mysql, database

Any suggesions to convert MS ACCESS DB TO MYSQL ONE , qny idea will be thankfull , there is no contraint on the programming language, all what matte is the result , hanks in advance

Comment: google: "export MS ACCESS TO MYSQL" results: http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9LxGF3Qc90 ....

Comment: thank you for your reply, but what i need is a code with sql queries that i can run it to get the result , hope you get the point :)

Comment: I think you could open the Access database using MSSQL Management studio, export it to csv or generate SQL insert scripts, and then import csv file into mysql, or try running insert scripts (I think the last one may fail, depending on your data, the queries may need to be corrected): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639711/easiest-way-to-generate-insert-statements-from-ms-access-data ; https://superuser.com/questions/51777/connect-to-an-ms-access-database-from-sql-management-studio